# Qt выпадающий список в tableview

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, tableview

Как организовать выпадающий список в `tableview`? Использую `databinding` с sqlite. В одном из столбцов есть элементы, которые нужно представить на выбор выпадающим списком.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если данные выпадающего списка содержатся в отдельной таблице базы данных, то удобно использовать `QSqlRelationalTableModel` и класс делегата `QSqlRelationalDelegate`.

Для демонстрации предположим, что имеется таблица городов:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cities` (
    `city_id` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL
    , `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    , PRIMARY KEY(`city_id`)
)
```

... и таблица сотрудников, которые работают в этих городах:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `employees` (
    `employee_id` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL
    , `city_id` INTEGER NOT NULL
    , `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
    , PRIMARY KEY(`employee_id`)
)
```

Заполним эти таблицы данными:

```
INSERT INTO `cities` VALUES(1, 'Москва')
INSERT INTO `cities` VALUES(2, 'Санкт-Петербург')

INSERT INTO `employees` VALUES(1, 1, 'Иван Иваныч')
INSERT INTO `employees` VALUES(2, 2, 'Пётр Петрович')
```

Иван Иваныч работает в Москве, а Пётр Петрович в Санкт-Петербурге.

Теперь создадим модель и представление таблицы с использованием Qt:

```
QSqlRelationalTableModel *model = new QSqlRelationalTableModel();
model->setTable("employees");
model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
model->setRelation(1, QSqlRelation("cities", "city_id", "name"));
model->setHeaderData(0, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("ID"));
model->setHeaderData(1, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("City"));
model->setHeaderData(2, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("Name"));

QTableView *view = new QTableView();
view->setModel(model);
```

Ключевой строкой кода при объединении данных двух таблиц является использование метода `setRelation()` у `QSqlRelationalTableModel`. Первый аргумент метода - это индекс колонки в исходной таблице (в нашем случае `employees`), второй - объект объединения `QSqlRelation`, в конструкторе которого указываются наименование подключаемой таблицы, наименование её колонки, соответствующей исходной, плюс наименование колонки, содержимое которой должно подменять содержимое в ячейке исходной таблицы, если соответствие будет обнаружено.

Если запустить программу, то в таблице сотрудников вместо идентификаторов городов окажутся их наименования. Однако при попытке редактирования ячейки города раскрывающийся список с доступными наименованиями не появится. Для решения этой стороны вопроса достаточно подключить объект делегата `QSqlRelationalDelegate` к представлению:

```
view->setItemDelegateForColumn(1, new QSqlRelationalDelegate(view));
```

Разумеется, всё это будет работать только в том случае, если исходная модель получена наследованием от `QSqlRelationalTableModel` или прямым использованием объекта этого класса. Это не во всех случаях представляется возможным. Например, если модель получает данные из сети.

Для этого случая предположим, что имеющиеся таблицы `employees` и `cities` содержатся не в БД, а лишь как данные, например, в произвольном наследнике `QAbstractItemModel`. Также как и в первом случае потребуется делегат, который будет выполнять роль связующего звена между таблицами сотрудников и городов.

Файл **comboboxitemdelegate.h**:

```
#ifndef COMBOBOXITEMDELEGATE_H
#define COMBOBOXITEMDELEGATE_H

#include <QtCore/QPointer>

#include <QtWidgets/QStyledItemDelegate>

class QAbstractItemModel;

class ComboBoxItemDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate {
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit ComboBoxItemDelegate(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
        virtual ~ComboBoxItemDelegate() {}

        QAbstractItemModel *model() const;
        void setModel(QAbstractItemModel *model);

        int modelKeyColumn() const;
        void setModelKeyColumn(int column);

        int modelViewColumn() const;
        void setModelViewColumn(int column);

        virtual QString displayText(const QVariant &value
            , const QLocale &locale) const;

        virtual QWidget *createEditor(QWidget *parent
            , const QStyleOptionViewItem &option
            , const QModelIndex &index) const;

        virtual void setModelData(QWidget *editor
            , QAbstractItemModel *model
            , const QModelIndex &index) const;

    private:
        int _model_key_column, _model_view_column;

        QPointer<QAbstractItemModel> _model;

};

#endif
```

Файл **comboboxitemdelegate.cpp**:

```
#include <QtWidgets/QComboBox>

#include "comboboxitemdelegate.h"

ComboBoxItemDelegate::ComboBoxItemDelegate(QObject *parent)
    : QStyledItemDelegate(parent)
    , _model_key_column(0), _model_view_column(0) {}

QAbstractItemModel *ComboBoxItemDelegate::model() const {
    return _model;
}

void ComboBoxItemDelegate::setModel(QAbstractItemModel *model) {
    _model = model;
}

int ComboBoxItemDelegate::modelKeyColumn() const {
    return _model_key_column;
}

void ComboBoxItemDelegate::setModelKeyColumn(int column) {
    _model_key_column = column;
}

int ComboBoxItemDelegate::modelViewColumn() const {
    return _model_view_column;
}

void ComboBoxItemDelegate::setModelViewColumn(int column) {
    _model_view_column = column;
}

QString ComboBoxItemDelegate::displayText(const QVariant &value
    , const QLocale &locale) const {

    Q_UNUSED(locale);

    if(_model.isNull()) return QString();

    while(_model->canFetchMore(QModelIndex()))
        _model->fetchMore(QModelIndex());

    QModelIndexList indexes
        = _model->match(_model->index(0,_model_key_column)
            , Qt::DisplayRole, value, 1, Qt::MatchExactly);

    if(indexes.isEmpty()) return QString();

    QModelIndex index
        = _model->index(indexes.first().row(), _model_view_column);

    return (index.isValid()) ? _model->data(index).toString() : QString();
}

QWidget *ComboBoxItemDelegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent
    , const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const {

    if(_model.isNull()) return;

    while(_model->canFetchMore(QModelIndex()))
        _model->fetchMore(QModelIndex());

    QComboBox *cbox = new QComboBox(parent);
    cbox->setGeometry(option.rect);
    cbox->setModel(_model);
    cbox->setModelColumn(_model_view_column);

    QModelIndexList indexes
        = _model->match(_model->index(0,_model_key_column)
            , Qt::DisplayRole, index.data(), 1, Qt::MatchExactly);

    if(!indexes.isEmpty())
        cbox->setCurrentIndex(indexes.first().row());

    return cbox;
}

void ComboBoxItemDelegate::setModelData(QWidget *editor
    , QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex &index) const {

    if(_model.isNull()) return;

    QComboBox *cbox = qobject_cast<QComboBox*>(editor);
    if(cbox == Q_NULLPTR) return;

    while(_model->canFetchMore(QModelIndex()))
        _model->fetchMore(QModelIndex());

    QModelIndex model_index
        = _model->index(cbox->currentIndex(), _model_key_column);

    if(model_index.isValid())
        model->setData(index, model_index.data());
}
```

Представленный делегает не претендует на применение и опубликован с целью демонстрации механизма ассоциации значений между моделями. Подключение и использование делегата:

```
QAbstractItemModel *employees = ... ;
QAbstractItemModel *cities = ... ;

QTableView *view = new QTableView();
view->setModel(employees);

ComboBoxItemDelegate *delegate = new ComboBoxItemDelegate(view);
delegate->setModel(cities);
delegate->setModelKeyColumn(0);
delegate->setModelViewColumn(1);

view->setItemDelegateForColumn(1, delegate);
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы хоть уточните про который tableview речь-то идет - QTableView из widgets или про TableView из QtQuick.Controls. В целом в обоих случаях пишется делегат, для первого случая у QTableView (точнее у его предка) есть метод [setItemDelegateForColumn](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#setItemDelegateForColumn), которому скармливается номер колонки и потомка QAbstractItemDelegate. Такового потомка я когда-то для [себя](https://github.com/aknew/CoinsVariationBase/blob/7ebf1cfcf17f68682a0b6ae810dd9c4e628ed923/comboboxdelegate.h) [писал](https://github.com/aknew/CoinsVariationBase/blob/7ebf1cfcf17f68682a0b6ae810dd9c4e628ed923/comboboxdelegate.cpp) и насколько помню он даже работал, но это было давно и работает ли он сейчас не знаю.

Со вторым случаем все проще - у TableViewColumn есть соотвествующее свойство delegate куда вставляется qml Item (например, как [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32671712/combobox-delegate-does-not-update-tableview-model), хотя скорее всего можно было и без Item обойтись), но сам я на практике этим не пользовался насколько помню, да и вообще с комбобоксом из QtQuick.Controls у меня натянутые отношения - то он не редактируемый, то редактируемый но на пробел забито раскрытие списка (поправили только в 5.4.1), то программно не устанавливается пустая строка в качестве значения